# NSFileManager -createFileAtPath fails with NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, ios8, nsfilemanager

Maybe I've just missed something in the documentation, but I can't find anything that says this behavior should have changed in iOS 8.

My app sets the current working directory to the `Documents` directory, then tries to create a file there using `NSFileManager -createFileAtPath`.  Prior to iOS 8 this works fine.  On devices running iOS 8, I get the following on the call to `-createFileAtPath:`

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
 reason: '*** -[NSFileManager fileSystemRepresentationWithPath:]: nil or empty path argument'
```

Here is a minimal code snippet that reproduces the problem:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] changeCurrentDirectoryPath:docsDir];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"temp.dat" contents:nil attributes:nil];
```

**Note the path argument on `createFileAtPath` is `"temp.dat"` -** **if I change it to `"./temp.dat"`, the call succeeds.**

Am I doing something stupid and this was just "accidentally" working in prior iOS releases?  Or did they intentionally change the behavior here?  Or is this a bug in iOS 8?  Other NSFileManager methods that take a `path` argument seem to be okay with just a filename (e.g. `-removeItemAtPath:@"temp.dat" error:&err` succeeds).

**Edited to add:**

This only happens on a physical device.  In the simulator, the above call to `createFileAtPath` succeeds.

Comment: `createFileAtPath` should be passed a full pathname. Append `temp.dat` to `docsDir` and pass that in. There is no need to change the current directory.

Comment: @rmaddy: I guess my point was that it worked in all versions prior to iOS 8 (this is an app that's been around since iOS 3), and nothing I can find in the docs suggests that it should have changed.  "temp.dat" is a relative path (same as "./temp.dat") - the documentation doesn't specify that it has to be an absolute path, and other NSFileManager methods accept that same relative path (with or without ./) just fine.  I'm leaning toward calling it a bug (either in the OS or in the documentation) and sending a bug report to Apple.

Comment: There is a brief mention in the iOS8 release notes that says "The file system layout of app containers has changed on disk. Rather than relying on hard-coded directory structure, use the NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains function or the URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error: method of the NSFileManager class.". However, this doesn't explain your error...

Comment: So, have you determined if docsDir is valid?

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, docsDir is valid.  Also note that creating "./temp.dat" succeeds, while "temp.dat" fails.  That would not be the case if docsDir was invalid, or if changeCurrentDirectoryPath had failed.

Comment: I have the same error. I prepended my path with "./" and now it works again. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I opened a bug with Apple and they closed it as a duplicate.  While that doesn't necessarily confirm that they consider it a bug, it at least confirms that I'm not the first to encounter this, and that the behavior did indeed change with iOS 8.

For now, the solution is to prepend `./` to the filename, or supply an absolute path.

Comment: You've got to be kidding me. My App Store app has been live for 6 months now and is now starting to crash because of this. Where was the warning from Apple???